# How to highlight selected text using css?

Tags: css, styles

how to highlight the selected one of the text like a button it should be highlighted for example i need like to be displayed in screen using css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwmv1.png)

Can anyone help me with a solution or link to share any information.

Comment: Please creata a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Agree, the question is not clear

Answer (score 6):

This is what you can do highlight text in html using CSS. As you drag over the text, the text will be highlighted

```html
<head>
<style>
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
}

::selection {
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Select some text on this page:</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> ::selection is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Firefox supports an alternative, the ::-moz-selection property.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.selected-text{
  background:#fff;
  color :#000;
  display:inline-block;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  padding :3px
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:800;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="selected-text">en</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```css
h1::selection, h2::selection {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
p::selection {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example of heading one</h1>
<br>
<h2>Heading two</h2>
<br>
<p>this is the content section<p/p>
```

Comment: Color and background are the only things that work with ::selection. Padding will not have any effect.